# XMLHttpRequest cannot load *…* Origin : * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin - ON THE SAME SERVER

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hey folks I am getting this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load *…* Origin : * is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin

error. But I don't udnerstand why?
one page is on a wordpress page and the other is a static but both are on the same server... or is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the two pages are on the same server does not matter, it has to be on the same domain.

To bypass this limitation you have to set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in your response from the server with the value "*"(be careful, it allows all) or a specific domain name "http://myDomain.com".

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok, I htink they are the same domain.. I mean, one is from 
mydomain/a and the other is from mydomain/b

Is there a security risk in doing this, and how do I make it happen? THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

The origin is determined by:

- protocol
- port
- hostname

All three have to be the same.

The server the page is on is not relevant (beyond it being rare that two URLs on two different servers will share the same hostname).

Note that `example.com` and `www.example.com` are different hostnames.